# Router can't access internet through ethernet cable

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I live in a dorm and want to use my Netgear router to get WiFi. I know the router works fine; I used it at home as a repeater for extended WiFi range. In my dorm there is a ethernet cable from the wall, which works when plugged directly into my Windows 10 PC.

Problem: I start the router, reset it, connect the ethernet cable, connect to the router via WiFi (can also access the router on routerlogin.net), but my PC tells me there's no internet connection on WiFi, and I cant access any sites.

Router: Netgear N150 Wireless Router WNR1000 v3

Comment: So have you checked to ensure the router get's an IP address in it's configs once connected to the Ethernet port? You may need to enable NAT perhaps on the router (maybe) or check for some sort of setting that allows you to clone MAC address in the router (or something similar). I'm just guessing with no research but there's you some things to look into potentially if you want. Again, quick thoughts only no research or reading over the document for the make and model router.

Comment: Some campuses use MAC address authentication to control devices connected to their network. So if you didn't bother reading the campus policy and your router doesn't work, this could be the problem. Most routers let you change your router's WAN port MAC address to "spoof" a registered address. But this can get both you and the registered user booted off the network and possibly the school.  Not recommended.